# Can I inject spring bean from JAR file?

Tags: annotations, spring-3

I use Spring 3 in my project.Then I face a problem when I inject spring bean from JAR file. In JAR file, there is class like;

```java
package test;

@Service("CommonService")
public class CommonService {
}
```

And i already used it like this;

```java
package com.java.test.app;

@Service(value = "OtherService")
public class OtherService {
    @Resource(name = "CommonService")
    private CommonService service;
}
```

In my spring-beans.xml;

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.test.app, test">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

But `@Resource` annotation doesn't work.Can I inject spring bean from JAR file?

Comment: Please show where you have defined the @Resource annotation in jar file class?

Comment: @Japs can I declare '@Resource' annotation in my jar file class. Currently it is not.

Comment: Of course you can. You need to define it otherwise you won't get it autowired.

Answer (score 0):

If at runtime your CommonService class is on the classpath and is within the base package you specify with component-scan, then you should be good to go. Try using @Autowired instead of @Resource.